# How to get circle bounds at northeast and southwest points on map gg?

Tags: java

I have 3 class Bound {Point ne,sw} , Point {double lat, lng} , Circle{ double radius , Point center} and i calculate below to get NE and SW coordinates of circle , but that's just how to get the limit in the plane, so how can i get the limit by the coordinates of google map ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Point cCenter = new Point(20.89, 105.77);
    Circle c = new Circle(1000, cCenter);
    Bounds result = MapHelper.getBoundFromCircle(c);
}

public static Bounds getBoundFromCircle(Circle circle) {
    Point ne = new Point(circle.getCenter().getLat() + circle.getRadius(), 
      circle.getCenter().getLog() + circle.getRadius());
    Point sw = new Point(circle.getCenter().getLat() - circle.getRadius(), 
      circle.getCenter().getLog() - circle.getRadius());
    Bounds bounds = new Bounds(ne, sw);
    return bounds;
}
```

Comment: You'd need some trigonometry: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260096/find-the-coordinates-of-a-point-on-a-circle - Just keep in mind that the angles you're looking for are 135 and 315 degrees from the y-axis. Alternatively use the vector from the center points to the corners and reduce its length to match the radius (e.g. normalize the vector and multiply it with the radius, then calculate the endpoint when starting at the center).

Comment: Final note: when dealing with large circles you might need to switch to polar projection. Your code, however, doesn't seem to need that as it seems to deal with a flat 2D surface.